# Swift Combine publisher/subscriber in different classes

Tags: swift, combine

I'm following this example: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/combine/ (modified it a bit) and it prints 1, 2, 3, as I expect.

```
class MyCounter {
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private(set) var value = 0 {
        didSet { subject.send(value) }
    }

    private let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

    func increment() {
        value += 1
    }
}

class PrintCounter {
    
    let myCounter = MyCounter()

    init() {
        
        let cancellable = myCounter.publisher
            .sink { value in
                print(value)
            }

        myCounter.increment()
        myCounter.increment()
        myCounter.increment()
    }
}

let printCounter = PrintCounter()
```

I am now trying to publish other values, Timer, Location coordinates, etc, and am not successful yet.

```
class MyTimer {
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private var value = 0 {
        didSet {
            subject.send(value)
        }
    }

    private let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    
    init() {
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        
        Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .map({ (output) in
                return output.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
            })
            .map({ (timeInterval) in
                return Int(timeInterval)
            })
            .sink { (seconds) in
                print("MyTimer: \(seconds)")
                self.value = seconds
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

class PrintMyTimer {
    
    let myTimer = MyTimer()
    
    init() {
            
        let cancellable = myTimer.publisher
            .sink { value in
                print("PrintMyTimer: \(value)")
            }
    }
}

let printMyTimer = PrintMyTimer()
```

Even though 'value' increments in MyTimer it's not showing in printMyTimer sink (print statement).

So I'm just wondering if I'm on the right track to be using Combine for this purpose to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether Combine is the best approach to this sort of problem is a bit subjective. Some people will say that the new async sequences are the future. But Combine works well, especially when there are multiple subscribers.

The reason your example does not work is because the subscription goes out of scope when `PrintMyTimer`’s initialiser is finished. That automatically cancels the subscription. Just like in `MyTimer`, you need to save the subscription to keep it alive:

```
class PrintMyTimer {
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let myTimer = MyTimer()
    
    init() {
        myTimer.publisher
            .sink { value in
                print("PrintMyTimer: \(value)")
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and I agree with your response on approach being subjective.  I do have multiple subscribers and so will stick to Combine for now.

Comment: As to the reason why the example code did not work, can you say why it works in PrintCounter?

Comment: It works in `PrintCounter` because there are three calls to increment the counter before the initialiser finishes. As soon as the initialiser finishes, the cancellable variable will be de allocated and, as that is the last reference to the subscription, the subscription will be cancelled. But you don’t try and increment any more values, so there is no evidence of that happening. With the timer you keep publishing more values after the subscription in `PrintMyTimer`’s subscription has been cancelled.